# Translation of journal page written in 1823

Tags: translation, german-to-english, handwriting

I found a journal whose earliest date appears to be the 1821. It appears to be written in Sutterlin text. I've attempted to translate these myself by comparing Sutterlin text to this but so far I haven't been able to get meaningful words, i.e. the German to English translation doesn't recognize my interpretation of the letter(s) as a German word.

Could you help translate this (2nd) page?

The family name is Bollinger.  This particular page is accompanied by a hand drawn painting of an urn that may be in a cemetery?

[image: Bollinger Journal, date 23 September 1823]

Comment: For the records: This is not *Sütterlin*, which only became popular after 1928, but rather *Deutsche Kurrentschrift* that used to be the standard handwriting in the 19th century.

Answer (score 4):

I can come up with the following:

> Nimm dies kleine Angedenken
>
> Freundschaft, Achtung weiht es Dir,
>
> Könnte ich das Schicksal lenken,
>
> Immer bliebe ich allhier
>
> Was sind doch der Menschenfreuden(?)
>
> Kaum daß man sich kennen lernt
>
> Muß man sich schon wieder scheiden
>
> Freund Ach! so lebe wohl
>
> Potsdam, den 23. September 1823
>
> Zur Erinnerung Deines Freundes W. Schierling

*Take this small souvenir*

*Friendship, respect it shall show*

*If I could steer destiny*

*I would stay forever here*

*How are man's joys*

*barely do we know each other*

*must we part yet again*

*Friend so fare you well*

An urn is relatively improbable. This text was rather written to somebody who left for somewhere far away (i.e. not *that* far away...) as a memento.

Comment: It's not "weist" in the second line, but "weiht". In the last line the missing word is "Acht" wich is archaic and means attention or care. A strange thing is that the preposition before "Menschenfreude" seems to be "der" and not "die", indeed, and which is hard to explain

Comment: Der Gebrauch eines partitiven Genitivs als Subjekt oder Subjektsprädikativum ist archaisch, aber nicht unbekannt.

Comment: Thanks @mach. I of course meant article, and not preposition in my comment

Comment: *Acht* doesn't make a lot of sense to my modern mind here. *Ach* I would understand, but there clearly seems to be a "t"

Comment: Das Zeichen ähnelt zwar einem *t,* aber das vorangehende *h* ist nicht damit verbunden so wie in den Wörtern *Achtung* und *weiht.* Deshalb halte ich es für ein Ausrufezeichen.

Comment: @mach Das könnte sein.